# I am attempting to create a working PHP contact form

Tags: php, html

At the bottom of this page under the section 'Quick Message' in the lower right there is a a contact form I'm trying to fix.

http://danielgruttadaro.chapter7ny.com

The form does not allow submissions that do not have all three sections filled out. However, I am receiving the error: 'sorry unexpected error please try again later' when the form is properly filled out. Below is the relevant html and php. Thanks for your help.

```
<form method="post" action="contact.php" id="contactform">
<div class="form">
<input class="col-md-6" type="text" name="name" placeholder="Name">
<input class="col-md-6" type="text" name="email" placeholder="E-mail">
<textarea class="col-md-12" name="message" rows="4" placeholder="Message"></textarea>
<input type="submit" id="submit" class="btn" value="Send">
</div>
```

Here is the php:

```
<?php

//Retrieve form data. 
//GET - user submitted data using AJAX
//POST - in case user does not support javascript, we'll use POST instead
$name = ($_GET['name']) ? $_GET['name'] : $_POST['name'];
$email = ($_GET['email']) ?$_GET['email'] : $_POST['email'];
$message = ($_GET['message']) ?$_GET['message'] : $_POST['message'];

//flag to indicate which method it uses. If POST set it to 1

if ($_POST) $post=1;

//Simple server side validation for POST data, of course, you should      validate the email
if (!$name) $errors[count($errors)] = 'Please enter your name.';
if (!$email) $errors[count($errors)] = 'Please enter your email.'; 
if (!$message) $errors[count($errors)] = 'Please enter your message.'; 

//if the errors array is empty, send the mail
if (!$errors) {

//recipient - replace your email here
$to = 'dan@chapter7ny.com'; 
//sender - from the form
$from = $name . ' <' . $email . '>';

//subject and the html message
$subject = 'Message from ' . $name; 
$message = 'Name: ' . $name . '<br/><br/>
           Email: ' . $email . '<br/><br/>      
           Message: ' . nl2br($message) . '<br/>';

//send the mail
$result = sendmail($to, $subject, $message, $from);

//if POST was used, display the message straight away
if ($_POST) {
    if ($result) echo 'Thank you! We have received your message.';
    else echo 'Sorry, unexpected error. Please try again later';

//else if GET was used, return the boolean value so that 
//ajax script can react accordingly
//1 means success, 0 means failed
} else {
    echo $result;   
}

//if the errors array has values
} else {
//display the errors message
for ($i=0; $i<count($errors); $i++) echo $errors[$i] . '<br/>';
echo '<a href="index.html">Back</a>';
exit;
}


//Simple mail function with HTML header
function sendmail($to, $subject, $message, $from) {
$headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0" . "\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-type:text/html;charset=iso-8859-1" . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'From: ' . $from . "\r\n";

$result = mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers);

if ($result) return 1;
else return 0;
}

?>
```

Comment: I would suggest `phpMailer` library which is easy to use.

Answer (score 1):

Most likely the machine that is running php doesn't have a mail server set up as well. The mail function requires that. You can use a library like:

https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer

and use an existing gmail account to send your email:

http://phpmailer.worxware.com/?pg=examplebgmail

which will let you mail yourself whatever they type in. This is what I use in almost all of my projects.

You can also use PEAR:

https://pear.php.net/package/Mail

Which I have also had luck with in the past. Godspeed.